# Unexpected behavior of binary search algorithm in python

Tags: python, binary-search

I am new to python. While trying to make a binary search function , i am facing and unexpected problem. I don't understand why this is happening. I tried to modify the code, but result is same every time. Here is the code:

```
def bsearch(s,e,first,last,calls):
    print(first,last,calls)
    if((first-last)<2):
        return (s[first]==e or s[last]==e)
    mid = first + int((last-first)/2)
    if (s[mid]==e):
        return True
    if (s[mid]>e):
        return bsearch(s,e,first,mid-1,calls+1)
    else:
        return bsearch(s,e,mid+1,last,calls+1)

def search(s,e):
    bsearch(s,e,0,len(s)-1,1)
```

This is what i type in shell and get as Output:

```
>>> s=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16]
>>> search(s,5)
```

Output:

```
0 14 1
```

Thats it. It doesn't search the element in the list.

Comment: Please, indent your code properly so we can test it!

Comment: As a style thing, also note that the conditions on `if` statements don't need to be in parens - so, you can have `if (last - first) < 2:`, `if s[mid] == e:` and `if s[mid] > e:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mistake is right here:

```
if((first-last)<2): #This always will be less than 2
```

Should be:

```
if((last-first)<2):
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be helpful to add more `print` calls throughout your code to find out what is actually going on. Start by looking at the result of the search:

```
def search(s,e):
    print(bsearch(s,e,0,len(s)-1,1))
```

You will see it returns False straight up. You already know it isn't recursing, so it must be hitting this branch unexpectedly:

```
if((first-last)<2):
    return (s[first]==e or s[last]==e)
```

Add a `print(first - last)` to find out *why* it would be going there. In your example, it will print -14, which is certainly less than two. Change it to test `last - first` instead, and it will give you this chain of calls:

```
0 14 1
0 6 2
4 6 3
4 4 4
```

and ultimately return `True`, as expected.

Comment: thanks, that worked well, But can you tell me how do i know whether an element is present in the list or not when i search for an element that is not present in the list, it behaves the same way.

Comment: @nkd2195 by checking the return value of `bsearch` (what I print out in `search`, consider `return`ing that value instead) - it is True if the value was found, and False otherwise. If you `return` it from `search`, then you would be able to do `if search(s, 5):`, and the code underneath it will execute if and only if the value was found.